# Creating a fiscal year (FY), fiscal quarter (FQ) time series when I have strings for FY and FQ

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a two features in my dataframe that are strings for fiscal year (FY) and fiscal quarter (FQ):

```
FY     FQ  
2008   3  
2009   4  
2009   1  
2010   2
```

I used  the following:

```
index=pd.PeriodIndex(data.FY, data.fq, freq='Q')  
data['index']=index
```

My output is as follows:

```
index  
2008Q1  
2009Q1  
2009Q1  
2010Q1
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
index  
2008Q3  
2009Q4  
2009Q1  
2010Q2
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's not working is that PeriodIndex is expecting as list of strings that describe all the indexes needed. You can provide the necessary list with a list comprehension

Creating the data :

```
data = { 'years': ['2008', '2009', '2010', '2011'], 'Q':['3', '4', '1', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


   Q years
0  3  2008
1  4  2009
2  1  2010
3  2  2011
```

creating the index with list comprehension and applying it :

```
index = pd.PeriodIndex([y+'Q'+q for y, q in zip(df.years, df.Q)], freq='Q')
df.index = index


        Q years
2008Q3  3  2008
2009Q4  4  2009
2010Q1  1  2010
2011Q2  2  2011
```

Note : You should have a look at [period_range](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.period_range.html?highlight=periodindex), it's simpler to use.